# Create User schema(s) level in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-core-2.1

I am at a very Green level in the SQL world.

I have a registration page in my application. This form asks for a couple of fields

- Username
- Schema names (checkboxes)

Now on the submit button of this page, I need to create a user with the provided username who would have access to selected/checked schemas.

I created a LOGIN & created user for DB

```
USE [MyAppDb]
GO

/****** Object:  User [CG-Login]    Script Date: 2/17/2020 3:23:59 PM ******/
CREATE USER [CG-Login] FOR LOGIN [CG-Login] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

*The same would be called from `Entity Framework Core 2.1` using (builder.UseSQl())*

How can I create user schema based?

Thanks!

Comment: What does "have access" mean? To `SELECT` and `INSERT`? what about `DELETE` and `CONTROL`, or `EXEC` (and all the other permissions).

Comment: @Larnu The use should have access to admin level access with the table that has schema provided (means that were checked in the page)

Comment: What does "admin level access" mean. There's 3 "admin" roles at database level (have admin in their name), so do you want them to have `db_accessadmin`, `db_ddladmin` and `db_securityadmin` roles? If so, the correct statement would be `ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [CG-Login];`.

Comment: To grant full permission on a schema and all objects within, `GRANT CONTROL ON SCHEMA::YourSchema TO [CG-Login];`.

Comment: Beware that granting a user CONTROL or ALTER on another user's schema is highly-insecure.

Comment: @Larnu db_accessadmin

Comment: @Kgn-web the `db_accessadmin` role does the following *"Members of the db_accessadmin fixed database role can add or remove access to the database for Windows logins, Windows groups, and SQL Server logins."* Nothing about that is schema related. You can't make a "database schema user", a `USER` is a database object, not a schema object.